# AngularJS location.path not working

Tags: angularjs

this has been posted many times but I'm still not having luck with this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  if (error && !error.authenticated) {
    $location.path('/login');
    console.log('new path: ' + $location.path());
  }
});
```

My app will in fact not go to `/login`, yet the console.log will return a value of `/login`. I've tried the `$apply` trick without luck mentioned in other threads but this is a very simple app at this point, no third party integrations where angular needs some additional help via `$apply`. Is there a variant to `$location.path()` needed when used within the context of `$rootScope`, or listening for `$stateChangeError`?

I'm sure this is something simple and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Can you post a plunker?

Comment: Not enough context to speculate about why it's not working. You would need to provide a way for people to reproduce it, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Emphasis on **minimal**, often you'll solve the problem yourself while trying to produce a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

I failed to mention I'm using ui.router and so switching to `$state.go('login')` seemed to make it work. Next time I will make sure to post a plunker to get something reproducible and perhaps solve my own problem :)